At any given point how to Collect HeapDump for the running program from a pod
I've got Springboot apps which uses OpenJDK running in container and runs as pid 1. These are non root containers and imx remote enabled. I am trying to generate heap dumps on demand for these running pods.
I figured for that I need to use jmap to write to the location but it seems per this , it always tries to write to /tmp which is readonly. How Can I overcome this and allow JVM to write a on demand heapdump to custom location or fix this ?
At the moment it seems it's hardcoded to /tmp why ?.
https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/jdk.attach/aix/classes/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachineImpl.java#L40-L45
what options do I have to generate heapdump for these pods on demand ?
Thanks

You could mount a networked drive (such as an EFS access point) to /tmp so that the file is written directly to the network share where you can access it.

The issue is jmap won't even write to any other path except /tmp so it seems the issue I am having is I have to make /tmp as writable which in my case is not possible as it's read only file system in container.

How do I collect heapdump to any other path for a running process.

Regarding readonly issue.
If the container is running with readOnlyFilesystem: true, you need to exclude /tmp directory by providing an emptyDir on that path.
First, add a volume such as:
volumes:
- name: tmp
  emptyDir: {}

Then, mount it:
volumeMounts:
- name: tmp
  mountPath: /tmp

And now apps inside the container can write in /tmp directory.
Regarding dump
jmap should support setting the dump location, example:
jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=/the/desired/path/dump.hprof 1

I think your issue is that the attach code expects java to be able to write something under /tmp, maybe the pid of the process and more, so it's not related to where you write the dump file, but it's more related to java not being able to create tmp files needed during the process.

This was fixed after creating /tmp was writable mount. I can confirm this works and I was able to write to my desired path, JVM expects /tmp to be able to create _java_pid1 file to be created by process.

Nice to know, this confirms it. Java needs to write a few things down in this case. I think it's reasonable to expect to have a tmp directory available for some writing.. even if it's a bit ugly that the path cannot be personalized

that's correct, hard coded path is a no, no. Also java needs to disable the pid file creation to work the logic for heapdump or any other part.
